# Azure ARM Failover group conditional association of a database

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am working on an ARM template where I can conditionally control the association of one of the databases in the fail-over group. Here is my sample resource template

```
 {
      "condition": "[variables('Resources').IsFailover]",
      "name": "[variables('SqlServer').FailoverGroup.Name]",
      "type": "failoverGroups",
      "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
      "location": "[variables('SqlServer').Servers.Primary.ResourceLocation]",
      "tags": 
      {
        "displayName": "Failover Group"
      },
      "properties": 
      {
        "partnerServers": 
        [
          {
            ...
          }
        ],
        "readWriteEndpoint": 
        {
            ....
        },
        "readOnlyEndpoint": 
        {
          "failoverPolicy": "Disabled"
        },
        "databases": 
        [
          "[variables('SqlServer').Databases.DBOne.ResourceId]",
          "[variables('SqlServer').Databases.DBTwo.ResourceId]",
          "[variables('SqlServer').Databases.DBThree.ResourceId]"
        ]
      },
      "dependsOn": 
      [
        "[variables('SqlServer').Servers.Primary.ResourceId]",
        "[variables('SqlServer').Servers.Secondary.ResourceId]",
        "[variables('SqlServer').Databases.DBOne.ResourceId]",
        "[variables('SqlServer').Databases.DBTwo.ResourceId]",
        "[variables('SqlServer').Databases.DBThree.ResourceId]"
      ]
}
```

I want to achieve something like associating the DBTwo(database) with the fail-over group only if a flag(input parameter) is true and not associating if the flag is false all from the same group.

Is there a way to do this from ARM ?

Thanks in advance for any advice and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, arm template has support for conditionals (cough, cough). you can use `if()` function and several others (`and`, `not`, `or`, etc) to create conditions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-logical

so basic example:

```
if(equals(parameter('x'), 'FAILOVER'), true, false)
```

Comment: Yes it does. But what I am looking for is conditionally deploy resource which are a part of a failover group. 
When there is no failover i would have three databases as a part of the failover group and when it is failover i would have only two.

Comment: you need to use condition property of a resource in this case coupled with the `if()` function above