# Azure ARM failover group databases property not accepting a variable array

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to programmatically assign databases to a failover group using an ARM template, but I keep getting an error "InvalidResourceIdSegment". I found something close in the forums [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49675046/azure-arm-failover-group-conditional-association-of-a-database), however that was just for a single database so it wasn't quite an answer for my problem. I am basically trying to use a variable that is an array list of resourceIds for the databases I need to add to this failover group.

```
"databases": {
  "critical": {
    "names": [
      "DB1",
      "DB2",
      "DB3",
      "DB4"
    ],
    "ids": [
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases', variables('serverNameWest'), 'DB1')]",
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases', variables('serverNameWest'), 'DB2')]",
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases', variables('serverNameWest'), 'DB3')]",
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases', variables('serverNameWest'), 'DB4')]"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is a snippet of the failover group resource

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/failoverGroups",
    "name": "[concat(variables('serverNameWest'), '/', variables('failovergroups').critical)]",
    "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
    "condition": "[parameters('setRedundancy')]",
    "tags": {
      "Environment": "[parameters('Environment')]"
    },
    "properties": {
      "readWriteEndpoint": {
        "failoverPolicy": "Automatic",
        "failoverWithDataLossGracePeriodMinutes": 15
      },
      "readOnlyEndpoint": {
        "failoverPolicy": "Enabled"
      },
      "partnerServers": [
        {
          "id": "[resourceID('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('serverNameEast'))]"
        }
      ],
      "databases": [
       "[variables('databases').critical.ids]"
      ]
    },
    "dependsOn": [
      "[resourceID('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('serverNameEast'))]",
      "[resourceID('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('serverNameWest'))]",
      "[concat(resourceID('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('serverNameWest')), '/elasticpools/', variables('elasticpools').critwest)]",
      "[concat(resourceID('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('serverNameEast')), '/elasticpools/', variables('elasticpools').criteast)]",
      "BusinessCriticalWest",
      "BusinessCriticalEast"
    ]
  }
```

Passing in the variable `[variables('databases').critical.ids]` to the databases property always gives this error:

`"code": "InvalidResourceIdSegment",
"message": "The 'parameters.properties.databases[0]' segment in the url is invalid."`

However, if I add them individually, like below, everything works fine.

```
"[variables('databases').critical.ids[0]]"
```

I have tried using the copy function in both the property (which appears not to work since the copy function requires a name value pair for the input) and a copy function as a variable (which also returns the same error about invalidResourceIdSegment). I'm baffled so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `"databases": [
       "[split(variables('databases').critical.ids, ',')]"
      ]`

Comment: sadly that did not work. just as is I got an error because split expects the first argument to be a string, so I tried [split(string(variables('databases').critical.ids), ',')] but that got me back to the original error of "The 'parameters.properties.databases[0]' segment in the url is invalid."

Answer (score 0):

@nicklaws I just came across this when looking for something else.

At first glance firstly, I am wondering if this could be an issue:

```json
variables('serverNameEast')
```

As I can't see the setup of your variables, I can't tell but, mine usually look like this:

```json
variables('serverNameEast').name
```

for example.

Secondly, here is a whole ARM template which I have used many times and it works:

```json
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "businessOwner": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "NOT_SET",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Responsible for billing of the resource"
        }
    },
    "technicalOwner": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "NOT_SET",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Responsible for the technology decisions of the resource"
        }
    },
    "environment": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Provides information on the environment that the resource belongs to"
        },
        "allowedValues": [
            "prod",
            "nprd",
            "sand"
        ]
    },
    "costCode": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "NOT_SET",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Provides a charge code or cost center to attribute the bill for the resources too. This could be a project code or cost Centre"
        }
    },
    "projectName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "NOT_SET",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Provides information on the project that the resource group and resources belong to."
        }
    },
    "primaryAdministratorLogin": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "NOT_SET",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Administrator username for the server. Once created it cannot be changed."
        }
    },
    "primaryAdministratorLoginPassword": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "NOT_SET",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The administrator login password (required for server creation)."
        }
    },
    "sqlServerSecondaryRegion": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The location of the secondary SQL Server."
        }
    },
    "sqlServerSecondaryAdminUsername": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The administrator username of the secondary SQL Server."
        }
    },
    "sqlServerSecondaryAdminPassword": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The administrator password of the secondary SQL Server."
        }
    },
    "requestedServiceObjectiveName": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The name of the configured service level objective of the database. This is the service level objective that is in the process of being applied to the database. Once successfully updated, it will match the value of serviceLevelObjective property."
        }
    },
    "sampleName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "NOT_SET",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Indicates the name of the sample schema to apply when creating this database. If createMode is not Default, this value is ignored. Not supported for DataWarehouse edition. - AdventureWorksLT"
        }
    },
    "maxSizeBytes": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "107374182400",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The max size of the database expressed in bytes. If createMode is not Default, this value is ignored."
        }
    },
    "collation": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The collation of the database. If createMode is not Default, this value is ignored."
        }
    },
    "createMode": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "Default",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Specifies the mode of database creation."
        }
    },
    "readScale": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "Disabled",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Specifies the mode of database creation."
        }
    },
    "edition": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "Standard",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The edition of the database."
        }
    },
    "zoneRedundant": {
        "type": "bool",
        "defaultValue": false,
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Whether or not this database is zone redundant, which means the replicas of this database will be spread across multiple availability zones."
        }
    },
    "firewallDigitalNetworkFrom": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "NOT_SET",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "firewall rule"
        }
    },
    "firewallDigitalNetworkTo": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "NOT_SET",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "firewall rule"
        }
    },
    "firewallMelbourneOfficeFrom": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "NOT_SET",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "firewall rule"
        }
    },
    "firewallMelbourneOfficeTo": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "NOT_SET",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "firewall rule"
        }
    },
    "firewallSydneyOfficeFrom": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "NOT_SET",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "firewall rule"
        }
    },
    "firewallSydneyOfficeTo": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "NOT_SET",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "firewall rule"
        }
    },     
    "failoverEnabled": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "true",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Whether we allow a secondary SQL server with failover. This could be used to save money"
        }
    }
},
"variables": {
    "sqlServerPrimary": {
        "name": "[toLower(concat(parameters('projectName'), '-',parameters('environment'), '-', 'sqlsvr-primary'))]",
        "requestedServiceObjectiveName": "[parameters('requestedServiceObjectiveName')]"
    },
    "sqlServerSecondary": {
        "name": "[toLower(concat(parameters('projectName'), '-',parameters('environment'), '-', 'sqlsvr-secondary'))]"
    },
    "sqlFailoverGroupName": {
        "name": "[toLower(concat(parameters('projectName'), '-',parameters('environment'), '-', 'failover-group'))]"
    }
},
"resources": [
    {
        "name": "[variables('sqlServerPrimary').name]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
        "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "tags": {
            "BusinessOwner": "[parameters('businessOwner')]",
            "TechnicalOwner": "[parameters('technicalOwner')]",
            "Environment": "[parameters('environment')]",
            "CostCode": "[parameters('costCode')]",
            "Project": "[parameters('projectName')]"
        },
        "properties": {
            "administratorLogin": "[parameters('primaryAdministratorLogin')]",
            "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('primaryAdministratorLoginPassword')]",
            "version": "12.0"
        },
        "resources": [
            {
                "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
                "condition": "[equals(parameters('failoverEnabled'),'true')]",
                "type": "failoverGroups",
                "name": "[variables('sqlFailoverGroupName').name]",
                "tags": {
                    "BusinessOwner": "[parameters('businessOwner')]",
                    "TechnicalOwner": "[parameters('technicalOwner')]",
                    "Environment": "[parameters('environment')]",
                    "CostCode": "[parameters('costCode')]",
                    "Project": "[parameters('projectName')]"
                },
                "properties": {
                    "serverName": "[variables('sqlServerPrimary').name]",
                    "partnerServers": [
                        {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('sqlServerSecondary').name)]"
                        }
                    ],
                    "readWriteEndpoint": {
                        "failoverPolicy": "Automatic",
                        "failoverWithDataLossGracePeriodMinutes": 60
                    },
                    "readOnlyEndpoint": {
                        "failoverPolicy": "Disabled"
                    },
                    "databases": [
                    ]
                },
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[variables('sqlServerPrimary').name]",
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('sqlServerSecondary').name)]"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps",
                "type": "firewallRules",
                "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
                "properties": {
                    "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
                    "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
                },
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('sqlServerPrimary').name)]"
                  ]
            },
            {
                "name": "digitalNetwork",
                "type": "firewallRules",
                "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
                "properties": {
                    "startIpAddress": "[parameters('firewallDigitalNetworkFrom')]",
                    "endIpAddress": "[parameters('firewallDigitalNetworkTo')]"
                },
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('sqlServerPrimary').name)]"
                  ]
            },
            {
                "name": "MelbourneOffice",
                "type": "firewallRules",
                "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
                "properties": {
                    "startIpAddress": "[parameters('firewallMelbourneOfficeFrom')]",
                    "endIpAddress": "[parameters('firewallMelbourneOfficeTo')]"
                },
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('sqlServerPrimary').name)]"
                  ]
            },
            {
                "name": "SydneyOffice",
                "type": "firewallRules",
                "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
                "properties": {
                    "startIpAddress": "[parameters('firewallSydneyOfficeFrom')]",
                    "endIpAddress": "[parameters('firewallSydneyOfficeTo')]"
                },
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('sqlServerPrimary').name)]"
                  ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
        "kind": "v12.0",
        "condition": "[equals(parameters('failoverEnabled'),'true')]",
        "name": "[variables('sqlServerSecondary').name]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
        "location": "[parameters('sqlServerSecondaryRegion')]",
        "tags": {
            "BusinessOwner": "[parameters('businessOwner')]",
            "TechnicalOwner": "[parameters('technicalOwner')]",
            "Environment": "[parameters('environment')]",
            "CostCode": "[parameters('costCode')]",
            "Project": "[parameters('projectName')]"
        },
        "properties": {
            "administratorLogin": "[parameters('sqlServerSecondaryAdminUsername')]",
            "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('sqlServerSecondaryAdminPassword')]",
            "version": "12.0"
        },
        "resources": [
            {
                "name": "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps",
                "type": "firewallRules",
                "condition": "[equals(parameters('failoverEnabled'),'true')]",
                "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
                "properties": {
                    "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
                    "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
                },
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('sqlServerSecondary').name)]"
                  ]
            },
            {
                "name": "digitalNetwork",
                "type": "firewallRules",
                "condition": "[equals(parameters('failoverEnabled'),'true')]",
                "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
                "properties": {
                    "startIpAddress": "[parameters('firewallDigitalNetworkFrom')]",
                    "endIpAddress": "[parameters('firewallDigitalNetworkTo')]"
                },
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('sqlServerSecondary').name)]"
                  ]
            },
            {
                "name": "MelbourneOffice",
                "type": "firewallRules",
                "condition": "[equals(parameters('failoverEnabled'),'true')]",
                "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
                "properties": {
                    "startIpAddress": "[parameters('firewallMelbourneOfficeFrom')]",
                    "endIpAddress": "[parameters('firewallMelbourneOfficeTo')]"
                },
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('sqlServerSecondary').name)]"
                  ]
            },
            {
                "name": "SydneyOffice",
                "type": "firewallRules",
                "condition": "[equals(parameters('failoverEnabled'),'true')]",
                "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
                "properties": {
                    "startIpAddress": "[parameters('firewallSydneyOfficeFrom')]",
                    "endIpAddress": "[parameters('firewallSydneyOfficeTo')]"
                },
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('sqlServerSecondary').name)]"
                  ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Hope that is of some help.

Comment: thanks for looking at it. Unfortunately that won't work. I don't see in your template that you are defining databases at all. I see databases:[]. I am trying to iterate through my list of databases to apply them in a copy.

Comment: @nicklaws yes sorry. I for got I push the database into the server via another method. Sorry for leading you up the garden path.